# Am I reading in all the tweets from the search query

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I am trying to read in all tweets based on a hashtag within the United States. Usually after paging through all of the tweets I end up with around 400 to 500 tweets, which doesn't seem like a lot to me. I'm currently using node.js/express and [twitter-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key : "...",
    consumer_secret : "...",
    access_token_key : "...",
    access_token_secret : "..."
});

//The ID for the United States  place_type  in the Twitter API
var USAID = '96683cc9126741d1';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var moreTweets = function(id){            
        console.log(id);
        client.get('search/tweets.json', {q : "place:" + USAID +" #haiku OR #dog", count : 100 , max_id : id}, function(error, tweets, response){
                //If we get error back form twitter API we'll log it to the console
                if(error){
                console.log(error);
                throw error;
                }  

                //BaseCase no statuses are returned
                if(tweets.statuses.length > 0){
                    var message = "";
                    for(i = 0; i < tweets.statuses.length; i++){
                        var currentTweet = tweets.statuses[i];
                        //Do work on the crrent tweet
                        console.log(currentTweet);          
                    }


                var lastTweet = tweets.statuses[tweets.statuses.length - 1].id_str;
                moreTweets(lastTweet);
            }
        }
    )}
    moreTweets(null);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Try to look at this # with your smartphone, can you see more than 500 tweets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consult this page: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

> Please note that Twitter’s search service and, by extension, the
>   Search API is not meant to be an exhaustive source of Tweets. **Not all
>   Tweets will be indexed or made available via the search interface.**

I guess they have some limit for a search...